# Python CSV to Array

Tags: python

Need some help pls. I have a csv file in the following format. 
**input.csv**

```
Project1,folder1/file1,data
Project1,folder1/file2,data
Project1,folder1/file3,data
Project1,folder1/file4,data
Project1,folder2/file11,data
Project1,folder2/file42a,data
Project1,folder2/file42b,data
Project1,folder2/file42c,data
Project1,folder2/file42d,data
Project1,folder3/filec,data    
Project1,folder3/fileb,data
Project1,folder3/filea,data
```

Basically, ignore all columns except column #2. This column is like a directory tree, in the format `<foldername> forwardslash <filename>`. There is no header-row.

I wish Python ver 3x, to read this file and make this into an **array** in the following format. The input csv file is large and hence need an efficient way to this pls.

```
print(out_array)

'folder1/file1', 'folder1/file2', 'folder1/file3', 'folder1/file4'
'folder2/file11', 'folder2/file42a', 'folder2/file42b', 'folder2/file42c', 'folder2/file42d'
'folder3/filec', 'folder3/fileb', 'folder3/filea'
```

Each folder is output on a new row. The input csv file, will not have the folder names jumbled up. Hence, all rows for folder1 will be together, and not mixed with others.

Comment: Your "array" is not an array. What **exactly** are you trying to create? Do you mean a `list`? Please be specific and precise, vanilla python uses `list` objects usually, is that what you want? Or an `array.array` (don't think that would even work) or perhaps a `numpy.ndarray` (which would make much sense)

Answer (score 0):

If you can, use pandas. It should be efficient and fast enough for most of the cases.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv", usecols=[1], names=[0])
df[1] = df[0].str.split('/', expand=True)[0]
df.groupby(1)[0].apply(list).values
```

Result:

```
array([list(['folder1/file1', 'folder1/file2', 'folder1/file3', 'folder1/file4']),
       list(['folder2/file11', 'folder2/file42a', 'folder2/file42b', 'folder2/file42c', 'folder2/file42d']),
       list(['folder3/filec', 'folder3/fileb', 'folder3/filea'])],
      dtype=object)
```

`usecols` is basically to determine which columns to read. As you want to group by the folder, you split it and make a new column for folder. After that you group by the folder column to combine it into arrays. From there you can just get the values.

Comment: Using pandas is fine, but I do not wish to print the col-1. I wish to make it into an array, in the mentioned format.

Comment: @rogerwhite you don't print it there. As you can see, it just stores it into a variable. Which then, you can convert into array using `result.to_numpy()`

Comment: Thanks Bagus. but I dont understand. output needs to be in the mentioned format, one folder in each row. `print(out_array)

'folder1/file1', 'folder1/file2', 'folder1/file3', 'folder1/file4'
'folder2/file11', 'folder2/file42a', 'folder2/file42b', 'folder2/file42c', 'folder2/file42d'
'folder3/filec', 'folder3/fileb', 'folder3/filea'`

Answer (score 0):

To a pure python implementation, you should use the package [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Suppose the file you would like to read is in current directory with the `main.py`.

***data.csv***

```
Project1,folder1/file1,data
Project1,folder1/file2,data
Project1,folder1/file3,data
Project1,folder1/file4,data
Project1,folder2/file11,data
Project1,folder2/file42a,data
Project1,folder2/file42b,data
Project1,folder2/file42c,data
Project1,folder2/file42d,data
Project1,folder3/filec,data    
Project1,folder3/fileb,data
Project1,folder3/filea,data
```

***main.py***

```
import csv
a = []
b = []
with open('data.csv') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        a.append(row[1])

    for item in a:
        c = []
        for item2 in a:
            inicio = item2.split('/')[0]
            if len(c) == 0 and inicio in item:
                c.append(item2)
            elif inicio in item:
                c.append(item2)
        if c not in b:
            b.append(c)

print(b)
```

output:

```
[['folder1/file1', 'folder1/file2', 'folder1/file3', 'folder1/file4'], ['folder2/file11', 'folder2/file42a', 'folder2/file42b', 'folder2/file42c', 'folder2/file42d'], ['folder3/filec', 'folder3/fileb', 'folder3/filea']]
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I do not wish to print the col-1. I wish to make it into an array, in the mentioned format.

Comment: Thanks Dani; but not really. this will make all the rows into one single row of the array. Each folder should be a new row.....  `'folder1/file1', 'folder1/file2', 'folder1/file3', 'folder1/file4'
'folder2/file11', 'folder2/file42a', 'folder2/file42b', 'folder2/file42c', 'folder2/file42d'
'folder3/filec', 'folder3/fileb', 'folder3/filea'`

Comment: Thanks Dani, looks much better. but what if there are an undetermined number of folder1..folder2...folderN

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Danizavtz's revert; I post my solution...

```
Bdb = []
lastrowfldr=""
r=-1
with open('input.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    for row in (reader(read_obj)):
        fldr,x = str(row[1]).split('/')
        if (lastrowfldr!=fldr):
            r=r+1
            Bdb.append([])
        BdB[r].append(row[1])
        lastrowfldr=fldr
```